# Time Capsule will not connect to the internet or back up

Tags: time-capsule, internet

All lights are green except for internet and server.  I can not connect to the internet.  Things were fine until after my first back up.

Comment: What do the logs in the Time Capsule say - it should list error conditions for the internet connection. You may need to set it up again or load a good configuration if you have checked to "ignore" some of the error conditions that might lead to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the Airport Quick Assist and see which steps fail you.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1145

You can leave this question a general. "How do I start to troubleshoot my device" or edit it to list the steps you took and the specific error conditions. I'd be inclined to start a new question once you have more details and have narrowed down the issue.